# Request permissions not working within PermissionsPlugin for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For my Xamarin.Forms-App I'm using the https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin v2.0.1

If no permission is granted, I want to request the user to do so by `CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage)`

The problem is that the **function always returns `Unknown` instead of requesting the user for the permission**. One time, it worked...but I don't know what I changed that it's not working anymore..

Here my code:

**MainActivity.cs (Android-project)**

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**PermissionsExample.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PermissionExample
{
    public PermissionExample()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var requestedPermissions = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
        var requestedPermissionStatus = requestedPermissions[Permission.Camera];

        await this.DisplayAlert("", $"Permission: {requestedPermissionStatus}", "ok");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help! :)